# How does unique index solve the race condition in validates_uniqueness_of in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, race-condition

I know there is a problem with

```
validates_uniqueness_of :attribute
```

in RoR because of the race condition in the rare case that there are two requests, one immediately following the other.

The solution I've read was to put a separate unique index for each model requests, which would raise an error in the case of the race condition.

I don't get how that works.
If Person A makes a request, then Person B, they are getting assigned the same index? How does that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The race condition occurs because rails can't lock down the database and often runs multiple threads at the same time.

To understand how the race-condition occurs, think about what is needed for a uniqueness-check, and I'll give an example of two threads:

Lets suppose Person A and B want to save a new BlogPost with attribute `name` which must be unique.

1. Person A hits the save button
2. Person B hits the save button
3. Rails starts thread A that goes and queries the database to see if
   there are any BlogPosts with name "My BlogPost"
4. Rails starts thread B that goes and queries the database to see if there are any BlogPosts with name "My BlogPost"
5. Thread A returns "nope, no blogposts with that name, all clear to save"
6. Thread B returns "nope, no blogposts with that name, all clear to save"
7. Thread A saves the blogpost for person A
8. So does Thread B

...and now there's two blogposts with the same name.

There's nothing stopping this from occurring, this is because the "lookup[" and "save" actions are two separate things.. and thus can occur in the manner described above.

However... when you put a unique index on the database... what happens is this:

1. Person A hits the save button
2. Person B hits the save button
3. Rails starts thread A that goes and queries the database to see if
   there are any BlogPosts with name "My BlogPost"
4. Rails starts thread B that goes and queries the database to see if there are any BlogPosts with name "My BlogPost"
5. Thread A returns "nope, no blogposts with that name, all clear to save"
6. Thread B returns "nope, no blogposts with that name, all clear to save"
7. Thread A saves the blogpost for person A
8. Thread B tries to save the blogpost, but the database says "NOPE! I failed a uniqueness constraint"

Result: only one BlogPost with the name.

Now - to what you asked... and what I'm assuming is the mistaken understanding... and index is not an id.
Each record does not get the same index.
No record gets an index.

You can kinda pretend that an index is a lookup-table of all the values that are already set for this column.

What happens with a non-unique index is that you have a list of all the values... and the list of which records have that value. eg:

Widgets:
colour:
blue ids: 1,3,7
green ids: 2,4
red ids: 5,6

(totally made up example, nothing like reality)

When the index has a uniqueness constraint, it just has the same list, but only allows the db to store *one* id per value and if you try to store another one... it raises an exception

Comment: Using the `UNIQUE` constraint also means you need to be prepared for step 8 where you'll get an exception when saving. Try not to have your application randomly explode if this is to be expected and recover from it with a meaningful error.

Comment: Ah so Peron A is saving into the 7th column of the DB, and Person B would be accessing the same 7th column... which is a sign of the race condition occuring! Thank a lot! 

@tadman Yes thank you for the reminder :) I'll definitely put a page to save from that error

Comment: I'm curious, can this duplication also be avoided in rails with a unique column constraint instead of a unique index constraint ? As per this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/147/60829, both can be used in general for uniqueness(assuming  I'm not misreading this), the main reason for preferring a unique index constraint is when if that column is also being searched for in the website. If I'm not searching for that column for which I want to prevent duplicate entries and in general, I just need a unique constraint in the DB, can't a column level constraint be enough? Thank you very much.

Comment: quick answer: an index in rails is a uniqueness constraint... but not one backed up by the db. So if the index is on a column, it's a unique column constraint... but because rails can only ensure that it's unique from its own perspective, we can still get race conditions if the constraint is only expressed in rails. The best option is to create a uniqueness constraint in the db to ensure what you really want.